# Rspec testing if text is pluralized (Hartl 10.5 Exercise 1)

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.2
I'm trying to write an Rpsec (Capybara) to test if my page is properly pluralizing the word "Post".  I get an error when running my Rspec that states:

> c:/.../my_app/spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:58: in `block (3 levels) in ': undefined local variable or method 'user' for ... (NameError)

Here's the relevant test:

```
describe "profile page" do
    let(:user){FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
    let!(:m1){FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user, content: "Food")}
    let!(:m2){FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user, content: "Bar")}
    before {visit user_path(user)}
    it {should have_selector('h1', text: user.name)}
    it {should have_selector('title', text: user.name)}

    describe "pagination" do
        before(:all){40.times {FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user, content: "Food")}}
        after(:all){User.delete_all}

        it {should have_selector('div.pagination')}
    end

    describe "microposts" do
        it {should have_content(m1.content)}
        it {should have_content(m2.content)}
        it {should have_content(user.microposts.count)}

        before do
            sign_in user
            visit root_path
            User.delete_all
        end

        it "should pluralize post numbers" do
            FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user, content: "Food")
            page.should have_content("1 micropost")
            2.times {FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user, content: "Food")}
            page.should have_content("2 microposts")
        end
```

I'm not sure if I'm going about testing for pluralization of posts the right way either, but I'm mainly stumped about why that block can't "see" the users object since the line right after my if statement can see it.  if I comment out the if block everything runs fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any code outside of `it` doesn't have access to the variables defined with `before`, `let`, etc.  You need to place it inside an `it` call, say with a text argument that describes the total if/else test. Could you update this question to include the other code from your spec that's in scope?

Comment: updated.  Not sure if I get what you mean about the scope of `it`.  Is the problem that I put my `it {should have_selector('Post)}` within an if/else and doing so makes the `it` call lose scope with respect to the my `let(:user)` definition?

Comment: No, there's no problem per se with putting the `it ...` inside of the if/else, the problem is the reference to `user` outside of an `it` context.  Specifically, it's the reference to `user` in the `if (user.microposts.count ...` which I assume is line 58 in your file, the line number reported in the error. Generally, you set up your tests so that you don't have to use a conditional like this, but assuming you do need this logic, you'd want to create an encompassing `it` around both branches of the `if/else' and remove the `it` on each branch.

Comment: ah, that makes sense.  I can now see my testing strategy was wrong for the `if/else` block. I updated above with a new approach which feels in the direction you hinted at, but it still seems like I'm not totally getting rspec variable scoping.  The new test for pluralizing the word "micropost" doesn't pass and I narrowed it down to the fact that in the beginning in my `let!` I create 2 posts, which stay with the rest of the blocks.  I tried to delete them (`User.delete_all` does this) but they still stick around, thus causing my 1 micropost test to fail.

Comment: So, has your question been answered? Do you have a new one? In any event, you'll need to share the current information (i.e. spec, results) in order for me to provide additional help.

Comment: It has been answered and you're right, I now have a different issue.  I will fumble around (read: learn) a bit more on this and then post a new question.  Thanks, your explanation helped me understand testing scope better.

Answer (score 1):

Profile page doesn't have pluralization to test.
The test should be for static_pages#home.

```
describe 'Home page' do
  describe 'for signed-in users' do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before do
      FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user, content: 'Lorem ipsum')
      FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user, content: 'Dolor sit amet')
      sign_in user
      visit root_path
    end

    it { should have_content('micropost'.pluralize(user.microposts.count)) }
  end
end
```